# Visual Pathfinding between Visual Nodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, nodes, path-finding

I am working on an app in iOS, and I need some direction.
Basically with the app you can place new 'nodes' on the design sheet, and drag them around. Now what I want to do is build an algorithm that connects lines between the two, however they need to be squared off, so almost a pathfinding type algorithm I would guess. I'm not even sure what to search or what this is called, so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be wonderful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quantize your space into a grid, then use A* path search, allowing only horizontal and vertical moves.

To encourage the optimal paths to be more squared off (as opposed to including jagged diagonals), you can add a very small amount to the cost of a move if it involves a turn (e.g. previous move was horizontal, current move is vertical).

If you want me to elaborate more on what I mean, just let me know in a comment.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean, thats what I was thinking. How computationally expensive is the A* algorithm? Feel like that is overkill for what it is.

Comment: Actually, I had a better idea, what if I just took the x,y coordinates of the first and second node, then drew a line from x,y of the first node, then went to the x of the first node, but y of the second node, and then another line vice versa, if that makes sense. If not I'll try to explain better. :P

Comment: @MajorTom Are you going to have more than two nodes, such that connectors have to take routes around nodes? Or do the connectors just always follow an L shape between the two nodes they connect, ignoring other nodes that could be intersecting the connector?